# Maintaining Form Designs with one Geopackage to Multiple Different Projects

Tags: qgis, spatial-database, geopackage, forms

I work for an Archaeological consulting company in Australia and one of the major parts of our job is to go out and survey for aboriginal heritage sites before constructions can be approved. The requirements for recording are standardised from the government, so this makes creating forms quite easy.

I have been trying to move our documentation to a digitised method using QGIS, Mergin and Input. Which works great for what we need it for.

To do this, I am hoping to create a master form as a GeoPackage with all of the forms required for each of the site types we are likely to encounter in the field (Artefacts, Scarred Trees, Shell Middens etc). Then transfer this Geopackage to  the QGIS project for each separate job. I have created some nice looking forms that function well in Input.

The only problem is, I have to use a master project to keep the formatting and value map lists intact. If i copy and add the Geopackage with all the survey layers in it, all the form editing i did gets destroyed and i am only left with the fields again. The forms have quite a few entries and rather large value maps, so it is not something I can do at the start of each job.

Is there a way to ensure that the formatting for these forms gets carried over into new projects within QGIS, so i don't have to enter in all the value map information and ranges every time i start a new job?

Comment: Right click the layer, choose properties, at the very bottom, middle left, there's a dropdown called "style" (or similar). Choose "save as default" (third from the top) and then save to data base (not local). This saves all of your symbology, labels and form-settings to the geopackage.

Comment: Thank you so much Erik!